# css prefers media query over previous code

Tags: css, grid, media-queries

so i did some work with grid layout and wanted to change it in this media query:

```
@media(min-width: 700px){
#container{
    grid-template-rows: 320px;
    grid-template-columns: 320px 320px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
#left{
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
#right{
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
}
```

if I open the page in a normal browser it works but if I inspect element or show it on my Iphone it only shows the media query version.

here is a link to the page online:
[link to page](http://coab.be/signup/)

Comment: What is the question? It will only show the media query version on your phone, that is the whole point of a media query, to create different rules for different screen sizes. Here is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) to the mdn css reference. You also need to pay attention to browser compatibility which is shown at the bottom. You will notice that for IE when it comes to using grids there is a big X with red, which means it is not supported.

Comment: I wrote my css mobile first. so the media query is for a bigger screen.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to caniuse.com it mentions a known bug

"Safari does not yet support intrinsic and extrinsic sizing with grid properties such as grid-template-rows"

possiblyy your issue?

Comment: caniuse.com says it supports the latesr versions of safari. + tested it on chrome on the iphone and got the same bad result